# Slack Blocks? Limited by design for simple apps only?

Tags: slack-api, slack-block-kit

My application sends blocks to slack that require user decision about certain things. Let's simplify it and say it's a "yes" or "no" button click. The thing is--- the object this decision works should work on is a combination of `app_domain` -> `element_type` -> `element_id` -- those three fields are a MUST to identify which object to work on.

Maybe I'm reading the docs wrong, but it seems Slack is pretty limiting and there is absolutely no place to include a custom struct that'll go along with every message the ping-pong of app -> slack and slack -> app interaction. I am limited to `block_id` and `action_id` pretty much and there is absolutely nothing else I can put custom context-keeping data on.  I don't get this crude limitation. Do I really have no other choice other than putting `"xxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxx"` on the `block_id` string so that I can later decode those three IDs in my app to know what objects to work on when the user clicks an interactive button?

There's got to be a smarter way. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another customizable field in the blocks:

`private_metadata`

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/views

Comment: Thanks. It's amazing how I spent a day running around in circles in Slack's docs without encountering this